# SHA256 hashing a value in Python and VB.NET produce different hashes

Tags: python, vb.net, hash, sha256, hashlib

I am trying to re implement a hashing function in Python that had previously been written in VB.NET. The function takes a string and returns the hash. The hash is then stored in a database.

```
Public Function computeHash(ByVal source As String)
            If source = "" Then
                    Return ""
            End If
            Dim sourceBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(source)
            Dim SHA256Obj As New Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider
            Dim byteHash = SHA256Obj.ComputeHash(sourceBytes)
            Dim result As String = ""
            For Each b As Byte In byteHash
                    result += b.ToString("x2")
            Next
            Return result
```

which returns 
    61ba4908431dfec539e7619d472d7910aaac83c3882a54892898cbec2bbdfa8c

My Python reimplementation:

```
def computehash(source):
    if source == "":
        return ""
    m = hashlib.sha256()
    m.update(str(source).encode('ascii'))
    return m.hexdigest()
```

which returns
    e33110e0f494d2cf47700bd204e18f65a48817b9c40113771bf85cc69d04b2d8

The same ten character string is used as the input for both functions.

Can anyone tell why the functions return different hashes?

Comment: Look at the bytes.  It could be just the encoding is different

Comment: Maybe start with hashing an empty string (needs a change in your VB.NET code) or a single byte to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Microsoft's example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/301053/how-to-compute-and-compare-hash-values-by-using-visual-basic--net-or-v) to create a Visual Basic .Net implementation on [TIO](https://tio.run/##jVPBbpwwED2HrxjtpVhVrCZSe8uB3WwSpCSNyqo9G5iAI7CRMdvw9VsPLN5lk5XqCxr7zZs3b4Zteplpg7tdXDfa2BaSvrVYB/OQJ5h1Rtr@3D1fmb6xujCiKT@ANvhug@BJ512FMH6uggDcSboUnoRUIRtCOreyhjbRncnwVlgBkaOxRqpihrB1M2JCRohlb/H0/UG05Sevx9w3sBBpluNrUcq3hYd8WRkUFkFA2tPHGNHDq9FO2JALuUvmHu61OL4oWcXxWmU6d4r5EPF7tKSgDY9Ks@BipVWrK@R/nH/4KBWGhIqo2EaPLYeemrEjdbpuOqerdA1CKlrMQauz0sgGJ@wZ/0LyEF1//zFOKkGzlRm@GL2VOZqQ8T3tYNuhrqf6T7mUTmIvaAoG266yhxGS4Qeb77SBtchcD9OQIFaTZI@is@f5egMp98UW79eLg7xn2rFPPB1T2bhua5XTygVj9GLklsZ816nMSmfhx4aW/W9R0QLEynlz2CZ2Zi0l3cfKYoFmvtE/O@sY6HmYxJC67GRF3k/8/BFVYUs2c0g6077BRsMJCi7hambSvgSPmgZV7klDyU48OzFtCn6h7YzyND6HeesmowIKxv94t/sH). It is functionally equivalent to your implementation and I verified your string builder produces the same output as I'm unfamiliar with VB.

A similar python 3 implementation on [TIO](https://tio.run/##NYzLCsIwFET3@YpLNs0FyaKiC6Ff4aYgLtIkba6YB0kERfz2WKjuhjlnJr2qi2HfGvkUcwWnirvTxDwM/yyLU/3hKJBNFM5Zr4SrSRs7L45uXNqgo7GiU0UTdcguKVOogr9P/fjhco7Zqyo07sAGM3COsFaggQJsh1e2LZB5@UhGVSs2gD/gpbNPQ4stq4StfQE) produces the same hash as the VB example above.

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.sha256()
binSrc = "abcdefghij".encode('ascii')
# to verify the bytes
[print("{:2X}".format(c), end="") for c in binSrc]
print()
m.update(binSrc)
print(m.hexdigest())
```

So I can't reproduce your problem. Perhaps if you created a [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we might be able to assist you more.